# Jquery post not firing twice

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a form that whenever the user types something on the telephone field, the field value is sent to a php that will fetch any possible name and email for that telephone field and store it in a PHP session variable:

This is the jquery I have for the telephone field:

```
$('#tel').on('keyup', function() {
$.post('backproc.php?tel='+$('#tel').val());
$('#nombres').val('<?php echo $_SESSION['xnombre'];?>');
});
```

my backproc.php receives the info properly and retrieves everything from the database properly, no matter what i type, it is always being sent and processed by the php query successfully.

The problem is that according to my code,everytime I release a key on the telephone field, the value of the nombres field should change according to whatever I have on the session variable, and this happens, but only once and never fires again, worse yet, when it fires, it displays a previous session variable value, not the last fetched value, any ideas on what to do to always display the last fetched value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to echo the contents of $_SESSION['xombre'] in backproc.php and get it in jQuery like

```
$.post('backproc.php?tel='+$('#tel').val(), function(data) {
    $('#nombres').val(data);
});
```

see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `<?php echo $_SESSION['xnombre'];?>` code is generated on the server before the Javascript even gets sent to your browser. The code inbetween the PHP `<?` and `?>` tags never even get sent to the client at all - it's completely processed by the server. However, the Javascript is of course processed on the client.

You're getting confused between serverside and clientside code.

If you view the webpage source and look at your Javascript, you'll see what I mean.

Edit: Just realised that I told you the problem, without giving the answer! 2cents answer is correct though, so I won't repeat what he's already said.

Comment: Thanks Dan!! It really helped me a lot to undersntad that part about code being generated before the javascript, I fixed according to 2cent answer based on what you told me and now everything is working, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

keydown
Fires when the user depresses a key. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.
keypress
Fires when an actual character is being inserted in, for instance, a text input. It repeats while the user keeps the key depressed.

Hello,  "keydown" event works for your Situation(dont use key up,as it fires once as soon as you release key).
Use keydown (I am sure it works ,but if it does not use keypress)